# Unable to persist an object in mariadb, Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

I am trying to persist an object using the entity manager in a springboot application.

but I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval, last_updated) values ('5MIN', '2023-02-01 00:56:16')' at line 1
Query is : insert into cms_kpi_config (interval, last_updated) values ('5MIN', '2023-02-01 00:56:16.0')
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:125)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbStatement.java:242)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:210)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:186)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
... 223 more
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval, last_updated) values ('5MIN', '2023-02-01 00:56:16')' at line 1
Query is : insert into cms_kpi_config (interval, last_updated) values ('5MIN', '2023-02-01 00:56:16.0')
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:939)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQueries(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:775)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:201)
... 226 more
```

I don't seem to understand what the problem is.

here is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_kpi_config` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`interval` enum('5MIN','30MIN','60MIN') NOT NULL DEFAULT '5MIN',
`last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

here is my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cms_kpi_config")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CmsKPIConfig {

private Integer id;
private String interval;
private Date lastUpdated;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "interval", nullable = false)
@NotNull
public String getInterval() {
    return interval;
}

public void setInterval(String interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
}

@Column(name = "last_updated")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public Date getLastUpdated() {
    return lastUpdated;
}

public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}
}
```

In my Dao service class, I'm using entitymanager as below.

```
private EntityManager manager;
this.manager.persist(obj);
```

[image]

Please help

Comment: Just a guess - interval is a keyword in MySQL/MariaDB

Comment: reported as [CONJ-1048](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-1048)